# Is math.sqrt or **.5 more Pythonic?

Tags: python

Is using math.sqrt() or **.5 more pythonic? For example, is writing math.sqrt(2) or 2**.5 more pythonic?

Influences to being pythonic include (1) being more readable, (2) being more common and (3) being faster or more efficient.

Comment: Readability is mostly subjective (i'd say `math.sqrt`), for more common you'd have to search github or similar, for performance you could use `timeit.timeit`

Comment: while i prefer `1 + 2` to `operator.add(1,2)`, I prefer `math.sqrt(2)` to `2**.5` because it a glance a novice might forget that means sqrt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. `math.sqrt`, being named, is ever-so-slightly more readable *on its own*, but in the context of a larger equation, might break up math that is more readable as `** 0.5`. <s>`math.sqrt` will be ever-so-slightly slower (less so if `from math import sqrt` is done to save an attribute lookup) due to lacking direct interpreter support (function call dispatch is generic, exponentiation has dedicated bytecodes), but the speed difference is immaterial in 99.999% of cases.</s> **Update:** Actually, on checking, `math.sqrt` is ever-so-slightly faster (on my CPython 3.7.2 x64 Linux build, it takes ~18% less time on small `int` inputs, ~6% less time on `float` inputs); apparently the direct bytecode support for exponentiation doesn't outweigh the costs of generic exponentiation figuring out it needs to do a square root.

**Basically, do what makes your code look pretty/readable *in context*.**

---

For those who care, my `ipython3` benchmark was basically just:

```
>>> import math

>>> %%timeit r = tuple(range(100))  # To get baseline for overhead not associated with square root
... for i in r:
...     i
...
1.6 μs ± 2.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit r = tuple(range(100))
... for i in r:
...     i ** 0.5
...
14.4 μs ± 23 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit r = tuple(range(100))
... for i in r:
...     math.sqrt(i)
...
12.1 μs ± 43.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit r = tuple(map(float, range(100)))
... for i in r:
...     i ** 0.5
...
11.1 μs ± 31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit r = tuple(map(float, range(100)))
... for i in r:
...     math.sqrt(i)
...
10.5 μs ± 5.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Subtracting the baseline overhead from each to get the cost of the square root operation alone got the final performance discrepancy of ~18% faster for small `int`s, ~6% faster for equivalent `float`s (that avoid going through type conversion, and for `** 0.5`, don't spend any time seeing if `int`'s exponentiation will work).

Comment: I left the struckthrough original assumption in mostly as a reminder to myself that while *usually* direct interpreter support beats generic function/method calls, you always need to test to be sure. :-)

Comment: Also note: The cost of repeatedly doing `math.sqrt` instead of caching  `sqrt` once and using that is actually larger than the difference between `** 0.5` and `math.sqrt`; the 10.5 μs for `float`s drops to 6.94 μs if you get `sqrt` with `from math import sqrt`, and just use `sqrt` instead of `math.sqrt` (still loading `sqrt` from globals; you're not making it local). In all cases, we're talking about a savings of hundred-millionths of a second per operation (we saved millionths only by doing 100 operations); maybe this isn't the first place to look for performance. :-)